# How to make slider images darker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have revolution slider installed on my WordPress. The aim is to put a dark overlay with `opacity=0.3` over the slides... I`ve tried to make overlay .div with absolute position, but it covered all slider including its control elements like "next slide", "previous slide" and others.

So, i need to put this overlay just between slide image and slider controls. I`ve found code with image

```
<div class="tp-bgimg defaultimg" data-lazyload="undefined" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-lazydone="undefined" src="http://wp-themes/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/slider1.png" data-src="http://wp-themes/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/slider1.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; visibility: inherit; opacity: 1; background-image: url(http://wp-themes/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/slider1.png); background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 0%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
```

Then i wrote this

```
 $('.tp-bgimg').before('<div class="slider-area-overlay"></div>');
```

Nothing change. I dont know why.

Next step: lets do it via css.

```
.tp-bgimg { position: relative; }

.tp-bgimg:before {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
}
```

Its cool, but slide image appears with no changes, and then, after 1-2 sreconds appear my css styles.

I really have no idea how to decide this problem, please help me.

Comment: You could try modifying the z-index of the overlay and slider controls.  Making the z-index of the controls higher than the overlay and the overlay z-index higher than the rest of the slider.

Comment: @Robert yes i could, but html code structure doesnt let me do this, because overlay div always over slider.

Comment: Revolution slider comes with its own overlay option, you can enable it and rewrite the background css for that. I usually do that and it works great.

Try to enable 2x2 black, and add this:
`.tp-dottedoverlay.twoxtwo {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%) !important;
}`

Comment: @Havihavi thanx man, i found it)))

Comment: Go to Slider settings -> appearance -> dotted overlay

Answer (score 11):

The Slider Revolution FAQ offers 3 solutions to this:

- Option 1) Enable their built-in overlay

  This can be found in the slider appearance settings, sidebar. You'll want to change the "Dotted Overlay Size" option:

  [image: enable dotted overlay option in slider settings]
- Option 2) Add one of the following CSS blocks to the "Custom CSS" for your slide

  *I personally added it to the Global Slider CSS, so it affected all my slides.*

  1. If your individual slides have captions:

     ```css
     .rev_slider .slotholder:after {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         content: "";
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
         top: 0;
         pointer-events: none;

         /* black overlay with 50% transparency */
         background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     }
     ```
  2. If your individual slides *do not* have captions:

     ```css
     .rev_slider:after {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         content: "";
         position: absolute;
         left: 0;
         top: 0;
         z-index: 99;
         pointer-events: none;

         /* black overlay with 50% transparency */
         background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     }
     ```
- Option 3) Use image editing software, e.g. Adobe Photoshop, to manually apply a dark overlay to your images, then use the darkened images as the slide background.

  The simplest approach is to add a layer above your image, paint it black, and then reduce the transparency of the black layer to around 50%.

  [image: Applying dark overlay to image in Photoshop]

---

The solutions and instructions provided by Slider Revolution are available [**here**](http://www.themepunch.com/faq/extend-image-overlay/).

Comment: @YPCrumble thanks for the feedback, I've updated the answer. I hope it's better now?

Answer (score 7):

First you must to extend style of `.rev_slider .slotholder` (not of `.tp-bgimg`), because the start animation creates additional elements.

Second, the slider creates a duplicate of your image for animation, that has z-index more than source image z-index.

Try this, it will work well.

```css
.rev_slider .slotholder:after, .rev_slider .slotholder .kenburnimg img:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 99;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Comment: But how do I keep the layers on top.. the text and image layers are also getting affected by the opacity level

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. I never would have found out on my own. :p

Answer (score 2):

Found a super easy way that works!

Create a new shape. Name the layer overlay and drag it to the top. Colour it black. Change opacity to 50%. Width and height should be 100%. Choose "Stretch" in Cover Mode. Almost done. One more step.

Finally, go to Behavior and switch Align to "Slide Based". This will truly stretch the overlay to 100%.

Can't find it? Check this link.

https://www.themepunch.com/faq/incorrect-position-or-size-for-text-button-or-shape/

Scroll to step 3. Adjust the Responsive Alignment.

Wish this was easier but it's not. Don't like the dotted overlay they include in the settings. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: On Style I had to align the layer centered (H and V) for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Just incase for video add z-index and change css class:

```
.rs-background-video-layer:before {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index:1;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an update for the Slider Revolution Version 6, since this won't work anymore in newer versions:

```
.rev_slider .slotholder:after,
#rev_slider_2_1 rs-sbg:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: rgba(30,30,30,0.5);
}
```

The secound entry will do it for this specific slideshow (#rev_slider_2_1).

To have a more common approach for all slides which is equivalent to the previous solution, you could use something like this:

```
.rev_slider .slotholder:after,
rs-sbg-wrap rs-sbg:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: rgba(30,30,30,0.5);
}
```